# Getting 'Missing required parameter: refresh_token' using Flask-dance with Google oauth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, oauth, flask-dance

I am using Flask-dance in order to authenticate users to my app. The auth provider is Google.

From time to time the following exception is raised:

```
2019-08-09 08:07:26 default[20190809t105407]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
2019-08-09 08:07:26 default[20190809t105407]  -- 0 --
2019-08-09 08:07:26 default[20190809t105407]  -- 1 --
2019-08-09 08:07:27 default[20190809t105407]  InvalidClientIdError was caught: (invalid_request) Missing required parameter: refresh_token
```

Looking around this problem I could find 2 directions to go with:

1. Use `offline=True` while creating the Google blueprint
2. Implementing error handler for `TokenExpiredError`

I did both and deployed my app to GAE but I still face the same error. From the stacktrace I understand that the error handler is being invoked but while the code tries to recover the 'refresh_token' is raised

My code: (The code is based on [Google QuickStart](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.0/quickstarts/google.html) and Flask-dance issue [143](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance/issues/143))

```
import oauthlib
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, flash, session, current_app
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
import os
import time
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors import InvalidClientIdError, TokenExpiredError

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID", None)
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET", None)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "TODO_TODO"
blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    offline=True
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")


@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    _revoke_token_and_empty_session()
    return redirect(url_for('app.index'))


def _revoke_token_and_empty_session():
    print('inside _revoke_token_and_empty_session')
    if google.authorized:
        try:
            google.get(
                'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke',
                params={
                    'token':
                        current_app.blueprints['google'].token['access_token']},
            )
        except TokenExpiredError:
            pass
        except InvalidClientIdError:
            # Our OAuth session apparently expired. We could renew the token
            # and logout again but that seems a bit silly, so for now fake
            # it.
            pass
    session.clear()


@app.errorhandler(oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.TokenExpiredError)
def token_expired(_):
    print('In TokenExpiredError')
    del blueprint.token
    _revoke_token_and_empty_session()
    flash('Your session had expired. Please submit the request again',
          'error')
    return redirect(url_for('app.index'))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print('-- 0 --')
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
    print('-- 1 --')
    user_info_url = 'https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo'
    try:
        resp = google.get(user_info_url)
    except InvalidClientIdError as e:
        #
        # Here is the problem
        #
        print('InvalidClientIdError was caught: {}'.format(str(e)))
        return 'Having an InvalidClientIdError issue: {}'.format(str(e)), 500
    else:
        print('-- 2 --')
        user_info = resp.json()
        return "You are {user_name} on Google. Time: {t}".format(user_name=user_info['name'], t=time.time())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My current understanding is that the `TokenExpiredError` was caught and the function `index` was called. When the function tries to call `resp = google.get(user_info_url)` the `InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) Missing required parameter: refresh_token` is raised.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Before you run `del blueprint.token`, print out the contents of that variable. It should be a dictionary -- is there a `refresh_token` key in that dictionary? If not, then Google isn't giving you a refresh token, so, Flask-Dance can't send it.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, and flask code, looks like you are trying to delete the token before revoking it, even though it's already invalid. If you want to avoid passing "offline=True" then try to simplify the code since there is no need to flash anything (the user will be redirected), and the token is already invalid, so it doesn't make much sense to revoke it either. I'm also setting only one error handler.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
import oauthlib
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, flash, session, current_app
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
import os
import time
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors import InvalidClientIdError, TokenExpiredError

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID", None)
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET", None)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "TODO_TODO"
blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    offline=True
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")


@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    """
    This endpoint tries to revoke the token
    and then it clears the session
    """
    if google.authorized:
        try:
            google.get(
                'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke',
                params={
                    'token':
                        current_app.blueprints['google'].token['access_token']},
            )
        except TokenExpiredError:
            pass
        except InvalidClientIdError:
            # Our OAuth session apparently expired. We could renew the token
            # and logout again but that seems a bit silly, so for now fake
            # it.
            pass
    _empty_session()
    return redirect(url_for('app.index'))


def _empty_session():
    """
    Deletes the google token and clears the session
    """
    if 'google' in current_app.blueprints and hasattr(current_app.blueprints['google'], 'token'):
        del current_app.blueprints['google'].token
    session.clear()


@app.errorhandler(oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.TokenExpiredError)
@app.errorhandler(oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientIdError)
def token_expired(_):
    _empty_session()
    return redirect(url_for('app.index'))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    print('-- 0 --')
    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
    print('-- 1 --')
    user_info_url = 'https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo'
    resp = google.get(user_info_url)
    user_info = resp.json()
    return "You are {user_name} on Google. Time: {t}".format(user_name=user_info['name'], t=time.time())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```